# Are Kakegurui (Compulsive Gambler) episode 3 calculations correct?

Tags: compulsive-gambler

Kakegurui episode 3 (Slit-Eyed Woman) calculations seem to be wrong. In the second round Yumeko put 40 chips (40 million yen) on 24th house and she says if the sword falls in the 24th hole, it would be **2 billion and 170 million yen**. How is this possible?

```
40,000,000 x 30 = 1,200,000,000 = 1.2 billion ≠  2.17 billion
```

Moreover, when she lost, Yuriko won because she put 5 chips (5 million yen) on 7th house. Yumeko had to pay **310 million yen**.

Yumeko debt should be:

```
(5 x 30) - 40 = 150 - 40 = 110 chips = 110 million yen ≠ 310 million yen
 △          △
 |          |
 Yuriko bet |
           Yumeko chips
```

OR

```
(5 x 30) - 40 + 40 = 150 chips = 150 million yen ≠ 310 million yen
 △          △    △
 |          |    |
 Yuriko bet |   Yumeko game entry
           Yumeko chips
```

Did I forget something? I mean there are lots of editors and proofreaders before printing a manga, let alone anime production. I think there is something about it that I don't know, because this mistake is too obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yumeko received 35 (losing) chips from Yuriko and paid 150 chips to Yuriko's Life win (5 chips x 30) for a net total of -115 million yen.

Yuriko received 40 of Yumeko's (losing) chips + 150 chips for her Life win (5 chips x 30) + kept her 5 (winning) chips for a net total of 195 million yen.

Yumeko went below 0 chips and the game ended, with her net total being her debt (115 million yen), so 310 million yen (195 + 115) was paid to Yuriko.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But there's something I still don't understand, why 150 calculated twice? I mean 5 chips were life for Yuriko so 150 chips should be paid to Yuriko by Yumeko.

Comment: You forgot about the game ends when a player's chip total goes below 0 and the amount left at that moment will be that losing player's debt.  Yuriko so 150 (5x30) from Life, kept her 5 and took Yumeko's 40. Yumeko fell below zero chips, so the game ends and what's left is her debt (to the winner).